# Power BI on premise gateway switch connection

Tags: powerbi, connection, gateway

A Power BI report dataset is configured to UAT gateway connection. Then I would like to switch it to production gateway connection. Even though I have created production connection through "Add to gateway" dropdown item, the dropdown still have only the UAT connection shown. Seems Power BI does not support switch connection.

[image]

Comment: Does the prod gateway have a connection to the _same_ server, or a different one?  You can't use that to redirect a dataset to a different server.

Answer (score 0):

Did more research and found that Power BI portal only shows in the dropdown list the gateway connections which have exactly the same database server and database name. This is why only one option is listed.

I tried to update the the DB server and DB name through API successfully. It automatically maps to UAT connection.

It is helpful if Microsoft provides an option on this UI to allow user to choose a different connection.